# How to prove that the number 6+2 can be represented as the sum of two coprime numbers?

Tags: gcd-and-lcm, coprime

$k$ is a natural number. How can I prove that the number $6k+2$ can be represented as a sum of two coprime numbers?

The greatest common divisor of two coprime numbers is $1$:
For integers $m,n$, $\gcd(a,b) = ma+nb = 1$.

But what can I do from here?
(The answer can't be: $a = 6k+1$, $b = 1$.)

The tools for the answer can be the division theorem, Bézout's identity, or Bézout's Lemma.

Comment: How about $6k+2=3+(6k-1)$?

Comment: Maybe there is a way to use odd (2k-1) and even (2c) numbers to prove this?

Comment: If $a$ and $b$ are coprime numbers, then $a$ and $a+b$ are also coprime. So you want to find a number that is always coprime with $6k+2$, that number is $3$.

Comment: @Rezha Adrian Tanuharja you mean that if gcd(3,6k-1)=1 then gcd(3, 3 + (6k-1)) is 1 right?

Comment: Why not just $6k+2 = 1 + (6k+1)$? Then 1 is coprime to any other integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write $6k + 2 = (2k + 1) + (4k + 1)$. The two numbers on the right-hand side are relatively prime for any $k \in \mathbb{N}$ since $2(2k + 1) - (4k + 1) = 1$.